# LINQ statement value to ForEach C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, linq

```
SelectedStationCustomers
              .SelectMany(customer => String.Format("{0}", customer.CustomerTelephone))
              .ToList()
              .ForEach(customer => client.SendMessage("12345678", NEED VALUE HERE, textMessage));
```

How do I get the value from customer.CustomerTelephone, into the ForEach statement? I have tried with customer.ToString(), but that does not seem to work.

Comment: What does `customer.ToString()` provide within the `.ForEach()`?

Comment: Why are you using SelectMany? That will result with a `IEnumerable<char>`. Just use Select.

Comment: Please keep the tags relevant to the question, not your project in general.  Also, you forgot the [tag:visual-studio], [tag:microsoft] [tag:windows] and [tag:human-being] tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `SelectMany` in this case.  Just use `Select`.

And the `String.Format` does nothing for you in your example.

```
SelectedStationCustomers
    .Select(customer => customer.CustomerTelephone)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(customerTelephone => client.SendMessage("12345678", customerTelephone, textMessage));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved it. I used SelecMany because I originally had more columns to select that I took away.

Comment: SelectMany is not for selecting multiple columns. SelectMany is used to flatten multiple sequences into one sequence (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx). If you want to select multiple columns, do this `Select(x => new {x.Field1, x.Field2})`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Select instead of SelectMany:

```js
SelectedStationCustomers
              .Select(customer => String.Format("{0}", customer.CustomerTelephone))
              .ToList()
              .ForEach(customer => client.SendMessage("12345678", customer, textMessage));
```

customer will hold the CustomerTelephone value